# Error: Compile Error: unexpected token: public at line 37 column 0

Tags: apex, rest-api, compile-error

I am new to apex coding. I am trying to connect salesforce case to Jira issue and trying to fetch jira issue details onto a salesforce case.
In the user manual I got the following code:

```
public with sharing class JIRA {

    // Change values in this class according to you JIRA/Salesforce coordinates.

    public static String baseUrl = 'JIRA URL'; // Base URL of your JIRA instance
    public static String systemId = '1'; // Salesforce Connector System ID in JIRA
    public static String username = 'your jira username';  // JIRA username
    public static String password = 'your jira password'; // JIRA password

    public static String agentProfileName = 'JIRA Agent'; // Jira agent profile name in Salesforce

    // Constructs Basic Http Authentication header from provided credentials
    public static String authHeader(String u, String p) {
        Blob headerValue = Blob.valueOf(u + ':' + p);
        return 'Basic ' + EncodingUtil.base64Encode(headerValue);
    }

    // Sends a request and returns the response
    public static HttpResponse sendRequest(HttpRequest req) {
        Http http = new Http();
        return http.send(req);
    }

    // Detects whether current user is not JIRA agent. By calling this you can make sure that
    // infinite loops won't happen in triggers (for instance when synchronizing an issue with JIRA)
    public static Boolean currentUserIsNotJiraAgent() {
        Boolean allow = false;
        List<Profile> jiraAgentProfile = [SELECT Id FROM Profile WHERE Name=:JIRA.agentProfileName];
        if (!jiraAgentProfile.isEmpty()) {
            String jiraProfileAgentId = String.valueOf(jiraAgentProfile[0].id);
            allow = UserInfo.getProfileId() != jiraProfileAgentId;
        }
        return allow || Test.isRunningTest();
    }

}
public class JIRAFetchIssuesController {

    private String issuesJson;

    // Constructor of this class. Note that a request will be sent to JIRA when this class is constructed.
    public JIRAFetchIssuesController(ApexPages.StandardController stdController) {
        Case theCase = (Case)stdController.getRecord();
        this.issuesJson = getResultJson('Case', theCase.id);
    }

    // Sends request to JIRA and returns the request body which should be a valid JSON.
    private static String getResultJson(String objectType, String objectId) {
        try {
            HttpRequest req = buildRequest(JIRA.baseUrl, JIRA.username, JIRA.password, JIRA.systemId, objectType, objectId);
            HttpResponse res = JIRA.sendRequest(req);
            return res.getBody();
        } catch(System.CalloutException e) {
            System.debug(e);
            return '';
        }
    }

    // Constructs request needed to fetch JIRA issues from provided parameters.
    @testVisible private static HttpRequest buildRequest(String baseUrl, String username, String password,
                                     String systemId, String objectType, String objectId) {
        HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
        String basicAuthHeader = JIRA.authHeader(username, password);
        String endpoint = getEndpoint(baseUrl, systemId, objectType, objectId);
        req.setHeader('Authorization', basicAuthHeader);
        req.setHeader('Content-Type','application/json');
        req.setMethod('GET');
        req.setEndpoint(endpoint);
        return req;
    }

    // Creates the endpoint to fetch the issue from provided parameters.
    private static String getEndpoint(String baseUrl, String systemId, String objectType, String objectId) {
        return baseUrl + '/rest/customware/connector/1.0/' + systemId + '/' + objectType + '/' + objectId + '/issue/fetch.json';
    }

    public String getIssuesJSON() {
        return this.issuesJson;
    }

    public List<JIRAIssue> getIssues() {
        return (List<JIRAIssue>)JSON.deserialize(this.issuesJson , List<JIRAIssue>.class);
    }

    // JIRA Issue Object.
    @testVisible class JIRAIssue {

        public String summary { get; }
        public String project { get; }
        public String reporter { get; }
        public String key { get;}
        public String status { get; }
        public String resolution { get; }
        public String url { get; }
        public String type { get; }
        public String assignee { get; }
        public String description { get; }
        public String priority { get; }
        public String due_date { get; }

    }

}
```

And the VF page:

```
public class JIRAFetchIssuesController {

    private String issuesJson;

    // Constructor of this class. Note that a request will be sent to JIRA when this class is constructed.
    public JIRAFetchIssuesController(ApexPages.StandardController stdController) {
        Case theCase = (Case)stdController.getRecord();
        this.issuesJson = getResultJson('Case', theCase.id);
    }

    // Sends request to JIRA and returns the request body which should be a valid JSON.
    private static String getResultJson(String objectType, String objectId) {
        try {
            HttpRequest req = buildRequest(JIRA.baseUrl, JIRA.username, JIRA.password, JIRA.systemId, objectType, objectId);
            HttpResponse res = JIRA.sendRequest(req);
            return res.getBody();
        } catch(System.CalloutException e) {
            System.debug(e);
            return '';
        }
    }

    // Constructs request needed to fetch JIRA issues from provided parameters.
    @testVisible private static HttpRequest buildRequest(String baseUrl, String username, String password,
                                     String systemId, String objectType, String objectId) {
        HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
        String basicAuthHeader = JIRA.authHeader(username, password);
        String endpoint = getEndpoint(baseUrl, systemId, objectType, objectId);
        req.setHeader('Authorization', basicAuthHeader);
        req.setHeader('Content-Type','application/json');
        req.setMethod('GET');
        req.setEndpoint(endpoint);
        return req;
    }

    // Creates the endpoint to fetch the issue from provided parameters.
    private static String getEndpoint(String baseUrl, String systemId, String objectType, String objectId) {
        return baseUrl + '/rest/customware/connector/1.0/' + systemId + '/' + objectType + '/' + objectId + '/issue/fetch.json';
    }

    public String getIssuesJSON() {
        return this.issuesJson;
    }

    public List<JIRAIssue> getIssues() {
        return (List<JIRAIssue>)JSON.deserialize(this.issuesJson , List<JIRAIssue>.class);
    }

    // JIRA Issue Object.
    @testVisible class JIRAIssue {

        public String summary { get; }
        public String project { get; }
        public String reporter { get; }
        public String key { get;}
        public String status { get; }
        public String resolution { get; }
        public String url { get; }
        public String type { get; }
        public String assignee { get; }
        public String description { get; }
        public String priority { get; }
        public String due_date { get; }

    }
}
```

I am trying to save it and develop a visual force page based on it. But I am getting the Compile Error at column 37.

What would be the issue?

Comment: Attach vf page also...plz

Comment: Are you trying to save these two classes in one file?

Comment: @Ayub Ansari: I didn't write yet. but here is what I have:

Comment: @AdrianLarson: Yes, I am following the support documentation from altissan marketplace. https://docs.servicerocket.com/display/CFSJ/Connector+Fetch+REST+API+-+Showing+Associated+JIRA+Issues+in+Salesforce+Cases

Comment: I am getting the following error on the salesforce case object :Content cannot be displayed: No content to map to Object due to end of input

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't save two top level classes in one file. Save these classes separately:

**JIRA.cls**

```
public with sharing class JIRA
{
    // logic
}
```

**JIRAFetchIssuesController.cls**

```
public with sharing class JIRAFetchIssuesController
{
    // logic
}
```

Comment: Okay, let me modify and save it!

Comment: That worked let me try developing the vf page and get back.

Comment: @abhi If this answer [addressed your problem](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers), please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234) by clicking on the check mark/tick to the left of the answer, turning it green. This marks the question as resolved to your satisfaction, and awards [reputation](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) both to you and the person who answered. If you have >= 15 reputation points, you may also upvote the answer if you wish. There is no obligation to do either.

Comment: I am running into a issue again. I am getting the error "Content cannot be displayed: Malformed JSON: Expected '[' at the beginning of List/Set" in the VF page section. Any Ideas?

Comment: @abhi That's a completely separate issue and belongs in a separate question.